How the question separator function works when data from Google sheets is transferred to Google form
0
I am creating a student attendance system for the institution I work for.
This system will check the students recorded on Google Sheets every night and automatically add them to the form if a new class or student is added.
Here's the thing.
I have now created all classes, courses and lists, but I could not redirect according to the class selected in the 2nd question.
Whichever class is selected and called forward, the student list of that class should come.
Then it should say send the form
I share my code below.

function updateFormDropdownFromSheets() {
  // Formu belirli bir ID'ye göre aç
  const form = FormApp.openById("1AHf-1pc_ONEoiSg6_o7xRJ63xcZUNGSmUl4YtgzCmAQ");
  // Formdaki öğeleri al
  const formItems = form.getItems();

  // Google Sheets'ten verileri al
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1vnqLZLfiyd1iZjCka4ic2sC13QncLPQX78rIvPJXMgA");

  // Giriş Bölümünün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
  const firstSectionRangesAndNames = [
    { range: "Database!B106:B122", name: "Ders Seçiniz" },
    { range: "Database!E103:E110", name: "Sınıf Seçiniz" }
  ];

  // YKS SAY-1 Grubu Listesi aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
  const section1RangesAndNames = [
    { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B3:B10", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
  ];


  // Birinci bölümü oluştur
  const firstSection = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
  firstSection.setTitle('Genel Bilgiler');

  // Giriş Bölümü
  firstSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
    if (existingItem) {
      // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
      if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
        const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
        const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
        // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
        const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
        const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
        listItem.setChoices(choices);
        Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
      const listItem = form.addListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
      Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
    }
  });

// Birinci bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
const firstSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
firstSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-1'); // Birinci bölümü temsil edecek bir başlık belirleyin


  // İkinci bölüm sorularını ekle
  section1RangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
    if (existingItem) {
      // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
      if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
        const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
        const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
        // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
        const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
        const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
        listItem.setChoices(choices);
        Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
      const listItem = form.addListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
      Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
    }
  });

  // İkinci bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
  const secondSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
  secondSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-2');

  // Üçüncü bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
  const thirdSectionRangesAndNames = [
    { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B3:B10", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
    // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
  ];

  // Üçüncü bölüm sorularını ekle
  thirdSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
    if (existingItem) {
      // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
      if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
        const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
        const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
        // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
        const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
        const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
        listItem.setChoices(choices);
        Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
      const listItem = form.addListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
      Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
    }
  });

// Üçüncü bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
  const thirdSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
  thirdSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-3');

  // Dördüncü bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
  const fourthSectionRangesAndNames = [
    { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B19:B34", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
    // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
  ];

  // Dördüncü bölüm sorularını ekle
  fourthSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
    if (existingItem) {
      // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
      if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
        const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
        const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
        // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
        const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
        const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
        listItem.setChoices(choices);
        Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
      const listItem = form.addListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
      Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
    }
  });
// Dördüncü bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
  const fifthSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
  fifthSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-4');

  // Beşinci bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
  const fifthSectionRangesAndNames = [
    { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B19:B34", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
    // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
  ];

  // Beşinci bölüm sorularını ekle
  fifthSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
    if (existingItem) {
      // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
      if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
        const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
        const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
        // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
        const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
        const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
        listItem.setChoices(choices);
        Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
      const listItem = form.addListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
      Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
    }
  });

  // Beşinci bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
  const sixthSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
  sixthSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-5');

  // Altıncı bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
  const sixthSectionRangesAndNames = [
    { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B19:B34", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
    // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
  ];

  // Altıncı bölüm sorularını ekle
  sixthSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
    if (existingItem) {
      // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
      if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
        const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
        const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
        // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
        const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
        const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
        listItem.setChoices(choices);
        Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
      const listItem = form.addListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
      Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
    }
  });
// Altıncı bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
  const seventhSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
  seventhSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-6');

  // Yedinci bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
  const seventhSectionRangesAndNames = [
    { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B3:B10", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
    // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
  ];

  // Yedinci bölüm sorularını ekle
  seventhSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
    if (existingItem) {
      // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
      if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
        const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
        const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
        // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
        const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
        const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
        listItem.setChoices(choices);
        Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
      const listItem = form.addListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
      Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
    }
  });

// Yedinci bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
  const eighthSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
  eighthSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-7');

  // Sekizinci bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
  const eighthSectionRangesAndNames = [
    { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B3:B10", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
    // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
  ];

  // Sekizinci bölüm sorularını ekle
  eighthSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
    if (existingItem) {
      // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
      if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
        const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
        const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
        // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
        const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
        const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
        listItem.setChoices(choices);
        Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
      const listItem = form.addListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
      Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
    }
  });

  // Sekizinci bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
  const ninthSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
  ninthSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-8');

  // Dokuzuncu bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
  const ninthSectionRangesAndNames = [
    { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B3:B10", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
    // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
  ];

  // Dokuzuncu bölüm sorularını ekle
  ninthSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
    const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
    if (existingItem) {
      // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
      if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
        const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
        const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
        // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
        const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
        const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
        listItem.setChoices(choices);
        Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
      }
    } else {
      // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
      const listItem = form.addListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
      Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
    }
  });

// Onuncu bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
const tenthSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
tenthSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-9');

// Onuncu bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
const tenthSectionRangesAndNames = [
  { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B3:B10", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
  // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
];

// Onuncu bölüm sorularını ekle
tenthSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
  const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
  if (existingItem) {
    // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
    if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
      const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
    }
  } else {
    // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
    const listItem = form.addListItem();
    const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
    const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
    const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
    listItem.setChoices(choices);
    listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
    Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
  }
});

// Onbirinci bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
const eleventhSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
eleventhSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-10');

// Onbirinci bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
const eleventhSectionRangesAndNames = [
  { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B3:B10", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
  // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
];

// Onbirinci bölüm sorularını ekle
eleventhSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
  const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
  if (existingItem) {
    // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
    if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
      const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
    }
  } else {
    // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
    const listItem = form.addListItem();
    const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
    const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
    const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
    listItem.setChoices(choices);
    listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
    Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
  }
});

// Onikinci bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
const twelfthSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
twelfthSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-11');

// Onikinci bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
const twelfthSectionRangesAndNames = [
  { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B3:B10", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
  // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
];

// Onikinci bölüm sorularını ekle
twelfthSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
  const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
  if (existingItem) {
    // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
    if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
      const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
    }
  } else {
    // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
    const listItem = form.addListItem();
    const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
    const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
    const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
    listItem.setChoices(choices);
    listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
    Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);
  }
});

// Onüçüncü bölüme ileri düğmesi ekle
const thirteenthSectionPageBreak = form.addPageBreakItem();
thirteenthSectionPageBreak.setTitle('LGS-12');

// Onüçüncü bölümün aralık ve isim çiftlerini tanımla
const thirteenthSectionRangesAndNames = [
  { range: "Sınıf Listeleri!B3:B10", name: "Öğrenci Adı Soyadı" },
  // İhtiyaca göre daha fazla soru ekleyebilirsiniz.
];

// Onüçüncü bölüm sorularını ekle
thirteenthSectionRangesAndNames.forEach(item => {
  const existingItem = formItems.find(formItem => formItem.getTitle() === item.name);
  if (existingItem) {
    // Eğer varsa, öğeyi güncelle
    if (existingItem.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
      const listItem = existingItem.asListItem();
      const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
      // Boş olmayan hücreleri filtrele ve değerleri al
      const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
      const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
      listItem.setChoices(choices);
      Logger.log(`Updated choices for ${item.name}`);
    }
  } else {
    // Eğer yoksa, yeni bir öğe ekle
    const listItem = form.addListItem();
    const range = ss.getRange(item.range);
    const values = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== "");
    const choices = values.map(value => listItem.createChoice(value));
    listItem.setChoices(choices);
    listItem.setTitle(item.name); // Soru kısmına aralık adını ekle
    Logger.log(`Added choices from ${item.name}`);

Required work: https://forms.gle/c5WTVD814CR8vQqT8
Code Runs: https://forms.gle/LHKiYpZbFzDpJTK67
Google SheetsData
enter image description here
